# Change the text in a div when a function is executed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function, used to increase and decrease the height of div.

This is the code

```
function chk()
{
    var node = document.getElementById('content');

    node.classList.toggle('expand');
}
```

Works with this `HTML` code:

```
<div id="hite">
   <div id = "content">
      This is dummy text.
   </div>
   <div id="button" onclick="chk()">
   click to read
   </div>
</div>
```

I want the text to change in `button` div, once user click on it, and when again click on it, text should be again 'click to read'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add this:

```
document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = node.classList.contains('expand')? 'hide':'click to read';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/Bup8u/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`innerHTML`** property.

```
 var ele = document.getElementById('button');
    if (ele.innerHTML == "click to read") 
        ele.innerHTML = "User click on it!";
    else 
        ele.innerHTML = "click to read";
```

Comment: When user again clicks on it, it should be again "click to read". How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use "textContent" if you want to add only text and not html data.

```
if(document.getElementById("button").textContent!='click to read'){

        document.getElementById("button").textContent="your content";
}else{
        document.getElementById("button").textContent="click to read";
}
```